# mysql group query by name and order by id and limit by id

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this

```
id   name   amount
 1   fish    120
 1   meat    230
 2   meat    110
 2   fish    78
 1   salad   50
 3   meat    103
 3   salad    22
 2   salad    34
```

i want to write a query that will group the names and sum their amount but it should limit to the first two id, thus group items by name and sum each matching name... this should limit it to the first two id. that is id 1 and 2 only. leaving id 3. Note. the ID is a foreign key from another table.

This is what i have tried. but it's not working

```
select name, sum(amount) from table1 group by amount, id order by id limit 2
```

this only outputs 2 results after doing the computation

```
name   amount
fish   198
meat   443
```

I am expecting something like this

```
name   amount
fish   198
meat   340
salad  84
```

Add the amount of items with id of only 1 and two and group them by name

Comment: because  your limiting the record  using  `limit 2` and group by should be `group by name order by id`

Comment: @John please check my answer

Comment: @John. double check the edisoni.1337's answer. For me it's incorrect. Try to remove 'salad' with id=1, or replace `2  fish` with `5 fish`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to limit to total output but you want to limit it before it makes sum so to do that you can use subqueries.

```
select t1.name, sum(t1.amount)
from table1 t1 join
     (select tt1.id
      from table1 tt1
      group by id
      order by id
      limit 2
     ) t2
     on t1.id = t2.id
group by t1.name;
```

Working example [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2a8868/8)

Result :

```
name    sum(t1.amount)

fish    198

meat    340

salad   84
```

Comment: This is exactly the same as the query I posted, down to the naming conventions and formatting.  Kudos on the wise formatting on queries.  (I should note that I don't downvote.)

Comment: @GordonLinoff your example is not working so check again you code :) you are making a join with a table that doesn't exist

Comment: I would say the answer is incorrect. If you remove 'salad' with id=1 it returns 34 for salad but expected is 56 (which is returned by my answer). But the answer is accepted. Who knows what is correct. (I am not the downvoter though)

Comment: BTW no need to group by id in the inner query. it enough `select distinct id`

Comment: @StanislavL You are correct this is not the correct answer but it's because the table is wrong because you see that you have duplicated id's

Comment: @edisoni.1337 No. It does not depend on duplicated id's. Your subquery leaves just first 2 ids. If there are 100 ids anyway your t2 results is 1 and 2. Suppose I have correct ids fish [1, 2], meat [3,4,5], salad [6,7,8] so your query skips all the ids [3,4,5,6,7,8]

Comment: Yes but with small changes is group by it is fixed :)

Answer (score 1):

```
select name, sum(amount)
from
  (SELECT id, name, amount,
       CASE WHEN @name=name THEN @rown:=@rown+1 ELSE @rown:=0 END as rn,
       @name:=name 
  FROM table1, (select @rown:=0, @name:='') s
  ORDER BY name, id
  ) sub
where rn<=1
group by name
```

output

```
fish    198
meat    340
salad   84
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name, sum(amount) 
  FROM table1 
 WHERE id <= 2
 GROUP BY name
 ORDER BY name
```

Comment: What if he has deleted two first id's and he runs this query ?

Comment: I didn't down voted it but i said you that this is totally wrong

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score -1):

What are the first two ids?  If I assume you mean "globally", then:

```
select t1.name, sum(t1.amount)
from table1 t1 join
     (select tt1.id
      from table1 tt1
      group by id
      order by id
      limit 2
     ) tt1
     on t1.id = tt1.id
group by t1.name;
```

Comment: I am not downvoter but it looks first 2 ids in each group (for each name just first 2 ids)

Comment: @StanislavL . . . It looks like the first two ids overall to me.

Comment: I posted my answer based on MySQL session variables. Guess the result could be achieved by joining the same table twice and including `t1.id<t2.id` in the ON section but require a bit more investigations

Answer (score -1):

Remove the `LIMIT` and only `GROUP BY` the `name`

```
SELECT Name, SUM(amount) AS Amount
FROM table1 
GROUP BY name 
ORDER BY id
```

Output

```
Name    Amount
fish    198
meat    443
salad   106
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2a8868/7/0

Comment: It's not what is required. For salad it's necessary to sum 2 rows only (first 2 ids) 50 + 34 rather than all group

Answer (score -2):

I think you can use something like this:

```
SELECT B.NAME, SUM(B.AMOUNT) AS AMOUNT
FROM (
      SELECT a.* ,
      @r:= CASE WHEN @g = a.NAME THEN @r+1 ELSE 1 END consecutive,
      @g:= a.NAME g    
      FROM DISHES a
      CROSS JOIN (SELECT @g:='', @r:=1 ) t1
      ORDER BY A.NAME, A.id
      ) B
      WHERE B.consecutive<=2
      GROUP BY B.NAME;
```

Output:

```
NAME    AMOUNT
fish    198
meat    340
salad   84
```

Comment: It has been updated... (I really don't like people who gives too much negative votes and hiding themselves too.)